# How resolve this Error Loading ModulesMySQL server has gone away for large joomla database website

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, joomla, phpmyadmin

I have developed a joomla website with a large database expecially the jos_users which is having about 2 million users..

I get this below error when i try to create a New contact in the backennd of joomla admin (contact component)

I have dedicated server and have told me host providers to see if there is changes to be done from their side or my side to the MYSQL server...

But they say the script needs to be optimized or something...  below is are the ERRORs

```
Error Loading Modules
MySQL server has gone away
```

SQL:

```
SELECT m.* FROM jos_modules as m LEFT JOIN jos_modules_menu AS mm ON mm.moduleid = m.id WHERE m.published = 1 AND m.access <= 2 AND m.client_id = 1 ORDER BY m.position, m.ordering
```

Errors:

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Unable to save result set in /home/jamesBOND/public_html/libraries/joomla/database/database/mysql.php on line 223

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/jamesBOND/public_html/libraries/joomla/html/html/list.php on line 152

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/jamesBOND/public_html/libraries/joomla/html/html/select.php on line 68

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/jamesBOND/public_html/libraries/joomla/html/html/list.php on line 201

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/jamesBOND/public_html/libraries/joomla/html/html/select.php on line 68

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/jamesBOND/public_html/libraries/joomla/html/html/select.php on line 68
```

kindly advise..

debug logged queries :

```
SELECT * FROM jos_session WHERE session_id = '0f293fd651b31502ec2be43876b'
DELETE FROM jos_session WHERE ( TIME < '1335799136' )
SELECT * FROM jos_session WHERE session_id = '0f293fd651b31502ec2be43876b'
UPDATE `jos_session` SET `time`='1335808136',`userid`='62',`usertype`='Super Administrator',`username`='admin',`gid`='25',`guest`='0',`client_id`='1',`data`='__default|a:8:{s:15:\"session.counter\";i:56;s:19:\"session.timer.start\";i:1335804352;s:18:\"session.timer.last\";i:1335808118;s:17:\"session.timer.now\";i:1335808124;s:22:\"session.client.browser\";s:109:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19\";s:8:\"registry\";O:9:\"JRegistry\":3:{s:17:\"_defaultNameSpace\";s:7:\"session\";s:9:\"_registry\";a:4:{s:7:\"session\";a:1:{s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":9:{s:27:\"com_advancedmodules_0search\";s:0:\"\";s:33:\"com_advancedmodules_0filter_order\";s:10:\"m.position\";s:37:\"com_advancedmodules_0filter_order_Dir\";s:0:\"\";s:33:\"com_advancedmodules_0filter_state\";s:1:\"P\";s:32:\"com_advancedmodules_0filter_type\";s:10:\"mod_custom\";s:36:\"com_advancedmodules_0filter_position\";s:1:\"0\";s:36:\"com_advancedmodules_0filter_template\";s:1:\"0\";s:34:\"com_advancedmodules_0filter_access\";s:0:\"\";s:37:\"com_advancedmodules_0filter_menuitems\";s:0:\"\";}}s:11:\"application\";a:1:{s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"lang\";s:0:\"\";}}s:6:\"global\";a:1:{s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:4:\"list\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:5:\"limit\";s:2:\"20\";}}}s:21:\"com_advancedmodules_0\";a:1:{s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:10:\"limitstart\";i:0;}}}s:7:\"_errors\";a:0:{}}s:4:\"user\";O:5:\"JUser\":19:{s:2:\"id\";s:2:\"62\";s:4:\"name\";s:13:\"Administrator\";s:8:\"username\";s:5:\"admin\";s:5:\"email\";s:25:\"bahrain.promote@gmail.com\";s:8:\"password\";s:65:\"da30ab3ea34d7ae9e04b8a7289344:j0EoSOVq4TtehmS4Qr5Q2iAahxFFiPAN\";s:14:\"password_clear\";s:0:\"\";s:8:\"usertype\";s:19:\"Super Administrator\";s:5:\"block\";s:1:\"0\";s:9:\"sendEmail\";s:1:\"1\";s:3:\"gid\";s:2:\"25\";s:12:\"registerDate\";s:19:\"2011-08-04 00:03:49\";s:13:\"lastvisitDate\";s:19:\"2012-04-29 23:04:51\";s:10:\"activation\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"params\";s:64:\"admin_language=\nlanguage=\neditor=ckeditor\nhelpsite=\ntimezone=0\n\n\";s:3:\"aid\";i:2;s:5:\"guest\";i:0;s:7:\"_params\";O:10:\"JParameter\":7:{s:4:\"_raw\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"_xml\";N;s:9:\"_elements\";a:0:{}s:12:\"_elementPath\";a:1:{i:0;s:64:\"/home/jatink/public_html/libraries/joomla/html/parameter/element\";}s:17:\"_defaultNameSpace\";s:8:\"_default\";s:9:\"_registry\";a:1:{s:8:\"_default\";a:1:{s:4:\"data\";O:8:\"stdClass\":5:{s:14:\"admin_language\";s:0:\"\";s:8:\"language\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"editor\";s:8:\"ckeditor\";s:8:\"helpsite\";s:0:\"\";s:8:\"timezone\";s:1:\"0\";}}}s:7:\"_errors\";a:0:{}}s:9:\"_errorMsg\";N;s:7:\"_errors\";a:0:{}}s:13:\"session.token\";s:32:\"1357096eb06e94b7329f1a5b9a1\";}' WHERE session_id='0f293b8fff7d651b31502ec2be43876b'
SELECT * FROM jos_components WHERE parent = 0
SELECT folder AS TYPE, element AS name, params FROM jos_plugins WHERE published >= 1 AND access <= 2 ORDER BY ordering
SELECT config FROM jos_fua_config WHERE id='fua' LIMIT 1
SELECT template FROM jos_templates_menu WHERE client_id = 1 AND menuid = 0
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_contact_details AS cd
SELECT cd.*, cc.title AS category, u.name AS USER, v.name AS editor, g.name AS groupname FROM jos_contact_details AS cd LEFT JOIN jos_groups AS g ON g.id = cd.access LEFT JOIN jos_categories AS cc ON cc.id = cd.catid LEFT JOIN jos_users AS u ON u.id = cd.user_id LEFT JOIN jos_users AS v ON v.id = cd.checked_out ORDER BY category, cd.ordering LIMIT 0, 20
SELECT id AS VALUE, title AS text FROM jos_categories WHERE SECTION = 'com_contact_details' AND published = 1 ORDER BY ordering
SELECT m.* FROM jos_modules AS m LEFT JOIN jos_modules_menu AS mm ON mm.moduleid = m.id WHERE m.published = 1 AND m.access <= 2 AND m.client_id = 1 ORDER BY m.POSITION, m.ordering
SELECT a.name, a.admin_menu_link, a.admin_menu_img FROM jos_components AS a INNER JOIN jos_components AS b ON b.id = a.parent WHERE b.OPTION = 'com_contact' AND b.parent = 0 ORDER BY a.ordering ASC
SELECT a.*, SUM(b.home) AS home FROM jos_menu_types AS a LEFT JOIN jos_menu AS b ON b.menutype = a.menutype GROUP BY a.id
SELECT * FROM jos_components WHERE `option` <> "com_frontpage" AND `option` <> "com_media" AND enabled = 1 ORDER BY ordering, name
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_messages WHERE state = 0 AND user_id_to = 62
SELECT COUNT( session_id ) FROM jos_session WHERE guest <> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

That's one big jos_users table, but the query you're asking about doesn't include that table at all, so it may be the sql statement that ran just before that one.  To see what it might be, turn on Joomla Debugging in the System Configuration, and see what the SQL statements are before that one - likely the last one on the page.

Comment: yes i know that the query is not using that table but i just thought i shud let u know that jos_users table is too big ...but anyways i forgot  to mentione that i get this error also above the lines of Error MySQL server gone away...

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/jamesBOND/public_html/plugins/system/advancedmodules/modulehelper.php on line 110

Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference in /home/jamesBOND/public_html/plugins/system/advancedmodules/modulehelper.php on line 337

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/jamesBOND/public_html/plugins/system/advancedmodules/modulehelper.php on line 110

Comment: Somewhere a SQL statement is timing out - you need to find that SQL statement( again, most likely the last one showing after you turn on Debuging), at which time the functions that are depending on the results will stop failing.

Comment: u mean from the queries logged? or from the _default namespace?

Comment: Could be either, but turning on Debug will show you the logged queries.  *Hopefully* you'll find the problem there, and won't have to look any further.

Comment: I have put the logged queries but really dont know where the problem maybe at

Comment: With debug on, then you should see a very large list of SQL statements that were executed.  What is the last, or second to last, one it shows? One of those SQL statements is likely the one that hung the SQL Server.