# Can Joomla handle Queries for Millions of Users in the jos_users table?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am almost done developing a large website.

The only problem is i get MySQL gone away errors all the time...

I posted another question here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387706/how-resolve-this-error-loading-modulesmysql-server-has-gone-away-for-large-jooml) but did not get my answer

So my Question is is Joomla fit enough or right CMS solution for a large users ( 5 million users)?

I have spent almost 5 months developing this... and now although i am on a Quad dedicated server (2 GB Ram) i feel that Joomla maybe perhaps not a right solution for this large database website..

Edit : I just want to make this clear I am not talking about the traffic...its brand new site. I am talking about the number of rows in some tables

Please advise

MySQL Server info :

```
MySQL error log: /var/lib/mysql/eta.etalenthunt.com.err

root@eta [~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
safe-show-database
open_files_limit = 5000
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
query_cache_limit=1M
query_cache_size=100M ## 32MB for every 1GB of RAM
query_cache_type=1
max_connections=100
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
character_set_server=utf8
delayed_insert_timeout=40
interactive_timeout=30
wait_timeout=60
connect_timeout=60
thread_cache_size=64
key_buffer=32M ## 32MB for every 1GB of RAM
join_buffer=1M
max_connect_errors=20
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_cache=2048
record_buffer=1M
sort_buffer_size=3M ## 1MB for every 1GB of RAM
read_buffer_size=3M ## 1MB for every 1GB of RAM
read_rnd_buffer_size=3M ## 1MB for every 1GB of RAM
thread_concurrency=8 ## Number of CPUs x 2
myisam_sort_buffer_size=16M
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=18M ## (>= 18M)
```

i am running dedi server XEON QUAD 2 GB

Comment: We can't really say anything useful about your case without some info on your MySQL server configuration, the load of your server (how much traffic per minute, for example?) and other factors, so if you could update your question, that'd be helpful :)

Comment: It's 5 million registered users (ie 5 million db rows) or 5 million users at a given time? if the latter, your site is a blast, get some investors and pump up those servers!

Comment: This is a job website...I have imported the users into the joomla DB.. i mean i have imported the jobseekers into the jos_user tables..

Comment: There are about  5 million of users imported... @Daan:  i will provide soon the details of my server

Comment: Its not the CMS type thats the answer to this question, its the host and server. Seeing as you have a dedicated server, I'm sure it will be fine. If things get too much then you should do as Damien Pirsy said.

Comment: So even at low loads, your MySQL server is randomly dropping connections?

Comment: yes i guess so...and i have posted the queries in another question in the stackoverflow ( see in the question above)

Comment: would probably be best you contact your host if you are having these problems at low loads

Comment: @Lodder Hostgator reply : 
This query alone is extremely resource intensive. While we can continue to adjust MySQL settings, unfortunately MySQL settings alone are not enough to prevent the site from possibly showing MySQL errors. You'll need to ensure that the queries running through Joomla are quick, by optimizing the queries that are going to be ran. Selecting only a handful of users, versus selecting ALL of the users out of jos_users would provide a much quicker response from MySQL, due to the very large amount of users within jos_users.

Comment: You need to post your query and data model here instead of your MySQL settings. The MySQL settings are not your first priority. If you query is too complex, or your additional database tables not properly set up, any MySQL tuning won't help. Selecting 20 records out of 5 Million rows won't be a problem, nor will any of the Joomla core queries that touch jos_users.

Answer (score 2):

OK! No problem. You have to realize that this is a common problem with Joomla and Wordpress (as I explained to you in my other answer to your another question here: [Is Joomla 2.5 much faster than Joomla 1.5 Querywise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474648/is-joomla-2-5-much-faster-than-joomla-1-5-querywise/10489776#10489776) )

#### Since you are working on it for past 6 months, and you already know its a huge huge database behind this website so what I am talking is exactly what can help you in limited boundaries of Joomla CMS.

I see this is an issue that you cant deal easily within any Joomla CMS! But there are some ways (in my opinion) that you can reduce the load a little here and there.

You can follow both of these steps, there could be more but let's try these two first:

**Solution #1: Split database into 2 or more databases**  (I will explain how to do that)
 **Solution #2: Hack Joomla core that hits user and session tables**
 **Solution #3: Split jos_users table into equal number of records**
 **Solution #4: Write a cronjob that cleans the session table**

#### Solution # 1 :

Step 1: Take your jos_users and jos_session table into two new separate databases. Call them db_jos_user and db_jos_session.

Step 2: Drop jos_users and jos_session tables from the main database.

Step 3: Create views for each of them with their respective names and point the tables using that db name.

```sql
CREATE VIEW jos_users AS SELECT * from db_jos_user.jos_users;
CREATE VIEW jos_session AS SELECT * from db_jos_session.jos_session;
```

This will actually reduce your database size and actually reduce the load on your database too. Joomla wouldn't be surprised and it won't know if it's view or the table behind it.

#### Solution # 2 :

Hack user authentication plugin and to authenticate users from different database by creating new instances of the database (that you split in following solution). You may develop a logic to determine which table to hit for which users. That way you might be able to reduce the load on your database(s). You might also have to implement a logic to insert/update users into their respective database. This is where you have to work on inside the Core User component and user login modules.

#### Solution # 3 :

You can split the tables into more database(s). In your custom authentication module, try to hit the databases one by one in a single query to all databases together using 'union' or one by one (that way you might save some database hits). You can sort them on username so that when they login you will know which database to hit. That will reduce your hits in great number.

#### Solution # 4 :

Write a cron job, that runs on a set interval which cleans the session table. Session table contains all info that belongs to a guest or a user. So you have to keep in mind that you clean it on regular basis. You can also do this if a user session is inactive for max 20 minuets or whatever you want you can delete it. You might need to put a notice on your website telling a user session if active more than 20 minutes will automatically be deleted or something more user friendly.

#### Conclusion:

Despite it seems silly when you are slicing your database and one table in particular into many pieces but actually it's ideal time for you to do that. It would not cost much of your time neither it won't harm your Joomla/Database. It's very easy to reverse though!

I hope all these would work for you. I don't see any problem in doing all these together except it gives you an overhead of work but actually its acceptable when you have +5mn records in your database.

I really really hope this will help you a lot in doing all these things together.

Comment: If these are actually real solutions that you need to use when you have a million records in the users DB in Joomla, I'm kind of worried. It shouldn't be a big deal at all if it has proper indexes...

Comment: Well I dont say they are real solution, but I have implemented some of them in my case and I am quite happy with that. Even if you have index the table, its better to have the 5mn records split into one or more database so that your execution will be faster. I dont see any disadvantage because its still easy to upgrade, easy to do rest of programming within Joomla CMS. I already have said in the beginning its within Joomla! CMS limited boundaries.

Comment: yeah it was not a comment at your specific answer (which itself is quite fine as far as I can tell), just something regarding Joomla itself :) Anyways, you're quite right that clustering will help with performance.

Comment: Thanks for this but Solution#2 and Solution#3 are a bit hard to understand for noob like me...can u plz. explain in little more details..thanks

Comment: I tried sol#1 and sol#2 but no difference..Still getting Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 314572800 bytes exhausted...

Comment: @soney_co, i will explain you how to do that. I am a bit in hurry now. Please contact me on my email or skype if you like I can share my details with you if you can contact me in a chat room on stackoverflow.

Comment: if #1 and #2 did not help, lets do #3. Sort your data on username. Put it 1mn records in each database. Then write a logic in your authentication plugin or hack Joomla core user login plugin to login your way. In your login logic, you will first identify which database to hit on the basis of user name You can hardcode this info somewhere so you can get username starting from a-d are in db1, e-j are in db2 and son on. You can keep session table in another table to reduce the database usage and size.

Comment: I am sure it will help you. Can you also share your website address? I mean if you have put this site on server somewhere provide me the login details I will see if I can help you for FREE!

Comment: i am checking things out again with your solutions...and if i get cannot get it right this time i will surely bother you...thanks for your support..:-)

Comment: No problemo! Let me know when you have any question.

Comment: @KMX: I resolved it ...Errors gone. I just added in my view.html.php a line at the top ini_set('memory_limit', '64M'); and in all component files where I used to get errors i added this one line script on the top of view.html.php and problems gone...But thanks for your extensive help...For now this works, if again i do have a problem i shall bother you..thanks

Comment: @sony_CO so what solutions you implemented so far?