# Is Joomla 2.5 much faster than Joomla 1.5 Querywise

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I wanted to know if Joomla 2.5 is much faster than Joomla 1.5. I am not expecting answers from the loading of the page content, libraries or motools libs etc. I am asking from the point of mysql queries...like will some join queries, multi queries etc for large mysql tables with 4-5 million rows?

I am developing a job portal for which i already have a database of 5 million jobseekers...and some queries take long time to execute or gives the Fatal error (memory allocated). So i was wondering if Joomla 2.5 would better serve my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions are same if you have millions of records.

Let me tell you why CMS (Joomla and Wordpress and likes) give you server timeouts when your website grows and the database becomes as giant as 5mn records!

1. CMS are systems that are developed to give you power to extend your website as a need arises.
2. Doing so, you develop extensions and keep on adding inline queries!!!
3. When you display a list of records (say 15 records per page) out of your 1mn records. CMS queries that table.
4. Along with #3, CMS runs many other queries behind the curtain to do other internal tasks such as tracking the hits, tracking the user and son on.
5. Along with #4, there might be several other Modules and Plugins that will be running on the same page regardless of your criteria of execution and may have some more inline queries (most of them sadly run lot of queries).

Now assume you have about 100 users. Came to load the same page for which I wrote above 1-5. Say this scenario executes about 10 mySQL queries then imagine how many would be executed if you have 100 users at a time?

When you have such large database - then you must implement load balancing. For now you can optimize your MySQL database if you have access to its configuration. You may look into increase sysvars like max_connections etc.

**Edit: Well "load balacning" is not upgrading your hardware but whole system and workflow that helps you achieve the goals with maximum optimization. Since you asked in comments, I want people know what it is about so including in my answer to make it more clear.**

Since you are having server timeout and its because of several million records in your database then you must think about something explained at following web locations:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742455.aspx

They might help you understand what I am talking about (could be off the topic) but you must seriously look into the possibilities how you could distribute your database or the load on your website so that you can allow them to execute queries quickly.

Comment: Thanks KMX  ...I will try to increase the max connections and see what happenss..meanwhile can u suggest something on [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405981/juser-load-unable-to-load-user-although-the-user-exists-in-all-3-main-joomla

Comment: implement load balancing? I mean i am using dedicated server XEON Quad 2GB.. do you think switcihing over to XEON QUAD 12 GB i better?

Comment: @ricardo, well increasing memory will help. I have a 32core Xeon proc, with 16gb memory and it works perfect, though it cost me about $8k /mo along with F5 load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to database queries, both versions of Joomla are around the same, Joomla 2.5 maybe being a little faster. The version you choose is entirely up to you. I personally love Joomla 1.5 however if this is your first time using Joomla then I would recommend 2.5 as they stopped supporting 1.5 last month I believe.

Comment: I love Joomla 1.5 native too..and have bought tons of extensions for that version...Have developed a lots of normal sites on 1.5. However its just that this project where i have millions of rows for 2-3 tables and i constantly get timeout or exhausted memory error that i was thinking perhaps the grass maybe greener (joomla 2.5) on the other side..

Comment: Try using Joomla 2.5 but I dont think there will be a major difference. What's your hosting like?

Comment: well obviously not a hosting issue lol, trying using Joomla 2.5 and see if this helps.

Comment: So since Joomla 2.5 is recently been released  no one can perfectly have an answer to my question i guess....Or perhaps moving my joomla website  to Xeon Quad 12 GB Dedi shud be a better option to speedup the MySQL queries?